# What does it mean when my hat has horns on it?

Tags: wario-land

I was walking around and hit an item block, and something that looked like garlic popped out. I grabbed it, hoping it wouldn't kill me. Good news is that I am not dead, but now my hat has horns coming out of it. What did I just do? Is this a good state to be in? How does it help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bull horn hat provides three abilities. The first is an improved version of your charge attack which can break blocks in one hit instead of two. The second is a groundslam which stuns enemies. This is executed by pressing down while jumping. The third ability is to stick to ceilings by pressing up while jumping. It is a good state to be in.